# Display the number of times a form has been submitted

Tags: php, database, wordpress, email, count

I have a wordpress website, on each post I have a html submission form that emails user info to me.

1) I need to be able to display how many times people have submitted the form (i.e. "xx people have submitted this form")

2) I need to store that number in a database and be able to call it on pages that display multiple posts on one page (for instance a search results page) - so that when there are several posts on display, you can still see "xx people have submitted this form" on each individual post.

Hope that makes sense. I know it's complex and my php skills aren't incredible so any code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

A screenshot of what I'm after can be found here: [SCREENSHOT OF WEBSITE](http://www.samskirrow.com/yourdream_edits.jpg) - you can see the form is under "Express Interest" and is just a submit button (the data is in some hidden fields)

Thanks, Sam

Comment: @Mahn nothing yet, not sure even where to start...any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Easy,

Create a column for submitted numbers.
Every time form successfully submitted add +1 to that column.

Comment: Thanks Muhammet, I'm a bit of a newbie with databases though, can you explain how I would code that?

Answer (score 0):

You should really think about an auto-increment id column in your database.

[autoincr](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

As an alternative you can write the number into a file with php...